# SSRS Multi Value Parameter filtering

Tags: sql, reporting-services, filter, parameters

I'm having a problem figuring out how best apply a filter on my data.

As a very basic example, my data contains the following columns:

```
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| REFERENCE | CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 | CAT4 | CAT5 |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| PL-001    |   50 |      |      |   50 |      |
| PL-002    |      |  100 |      |      |      |
| PL-003    |      |      |   25 |   25 |   50 |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I need the user to be able to filter on a multi-value parameter where the following works:

- If the user filters on CAT4 the table will show PL-001 and PL-003.
- If the user filters on CAT4 and CAT2 the data will show PL-001,
  PL-002 and PL-003.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT BELOW:**
My problem is that I need one filter but I have 5 columns. I have tried creating a new column that concatenates the category names applicable and then using a LIKE or CHARINDEX function on the parameter but this doesn't work for selecting multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this two ways, One with having filter in your query(SSRS) itself and other with creating Table/Matrix report and on that table add filter on Top.

Here are two excellent articles which will help you achieve your desired results.

[Article 1](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-multi-value-parameters-in-ssrs/)

[Article 2](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssrs-multi-value-parameter/)

Comment: These just seem to be instructional articles on how to use generic multi-value parameters. My problem is that I need one filter but I have 5 columns. 

I have tried creating a new column that concatenates the category names applicable and then using a LIKE or CHARINDEX function on the parameter but this doesn't work for selecting multiple values.